# Intergral Help for calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

Here is what I have. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You failed to integrate before evaluating.

Comment: Before you replace the variables in the integrand, you need to transform your equation into its antiderivative. Think about what the derivative of the second part of you formula (the exponential part) is.

Comment: set $t=6x^2-9$ and you will get $dt=12xdx$

Comment: What do I do with the dt and t? @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

First, let us find a antiderivative for $xe^{6x^2-9}$, by rewriting the integrand a little bit.

$$\int xe^{6x^2-9}\,dx=\frac{1}{12}\int12xe^{6x^2-9}\,dx$$

Now note that the $12x$ is exactly the derivative of $6x^2-9$, therefore the indefinite integral is equal to $\frac{1}{12}e^{6x^2-9}+C$.

It's up to you now to use the antiderivative to find the definite integral. I am sure you can take it from here.

---

**Edit**:

$$\int_1^4xe^{6x^2-9}\,dx=\left.\frac{1}{12}e^{6x^2-9}\right|_1^4=\frac{1}{12}e^{6(4)^2-9}-\frac{1}{12}e^{6(1)^2-9}=\frac{1}{12}\left(e^{87}-e^{-3}\right)$$

Comment: Now I just put 4 and 1 into x?

Comment: Yes, kind of, just solve the definite integral.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Substitute 4 and then substitute 1 into $x$ of the antiderivative and subtract those. I hope you are already familiar with this notion of definite integrals. @Ben

Comment: So I use the 1/12 equation correct?

Comment: you there? I just need a little more help

Comment: @Ben see the edit

Comment: Perfect! My answer is exactly the same a yours. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\int xe^{6x^2-9}\ dx=e^{-9}\displaystyle\int xe^{6x^2}\ dx$

$x^2=t \implies x \ dx=\dfrac{1}{2}dt$

$\therefore e^{-9}\displaystyle\int xe^{6x^2}\ dx=\dfrac{1}{2e^{9}}\displaystyle\int e^{6t}\ dt$